# What do they mean by "stabilizing height"

Tags: stability

I have found this text in an article:

"The most recent test saw the missile explode about two or three minutes after launch. According to South Korean military experts, **the missile reached an altitude three times higher than "stabilizing height**, which means the chances that any internal mechanical failure caused the explosion were very low," the Korea Times reported."

[Source](https://sputniknews.com/asia/201705011053177882-pyongyang-intentional-missile-test-failure/)

What can this "stabilizing height" be?

Answer (score 2):

In at least one instance, the "stabilizing height" is a reference to exhaust plume phenomena.

> The rocket motor's exhaust would be   emitted as   a  cloud at   an 
>   extremely high temperature. This high temperature causes the cloud to 
>   rise, while local winds tend to   move it   along laterally. As   the
>   cloud cools, it  stops rising, and the mechanical aspects of 
>   dispersion predominate. **The altitude at   which this occurs, referred
>   to   as   the stabilization height**, may vary greatly from one missile
>   type to   another based upon exhaust products, exhaust rate, and
>   exhaust temperature. Additionally, stabilization height would vary
>   from launch to launch due to   changes in   meteorological conditions.

(emphasis mine)

[Source](https://books.googleusercontent.com/books/content?req=AKW5QadyNlpaDBQtlR6pBK1maM8F149txIhbWe5yCI3VEKFrEN8s21D2fBeevwEKCrC1AwrLjy19olwuUUQc85ayZjYHg5sdv7j6uq3PnUIQrUi3XcUC2FxGYbr0jJ1XzYGXKyjWH-IWut2zfeBSWJANY9jMHj5VltMpOa9NhayqvwC4is-SmHPWG7Fpke9ZAJD0zkCPwkoIpR4jkdWZL5ioH1ApE8hG-UC-pEgN90XDxItiAUe6RjzFAmAc8a2RGm57Qqb826_W4kxBf2Btu8mWEAqnWcEFSSGXgjP6dE4m0_-Ix5IOuLU)

Comment: "...rocket motor's exhaust would be emitted as a cloud..." is imperfectly worded, but ya after a few secodns I suppose it slows down and turns into a "cloud". The source link does not work for me, returns Error 403 https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaHnH.png